# Delegated Event Handler Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use a delegated event handler on dynamically-loaded content, like so:

```
AjaxProt.prototype = {
    // bind handler - ensure to use $(document) to delay call to .on() method
    init: function () {
        var thisObj = this;
        $(document).on(thisObj.event, thisObj.targetEl, function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(thisObj.targetEl).attr('href');
            thisObj.ajaxRequest(url);
        });
    },

    ajaxRequest: function (url) {
        var thisObj = this,
            method = this.method,
            ajaxCallType = this.ajaxCallType,
            callback;
        // $.ajax here
```

`targetEl` is assigned to `[id^=startOfClassName]`. I tried to pass the `href` value from `init()` to `ajaxRequest()`, but it's still only selecting the first element matching the selector on the page. How might I be able to ensure that the `href` value is bound to the element that's actually clicked? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting time, I figured this out myself.

All I had to do was change `var url = $(thisObj.targetEl).attr('href')` to `var url = $(this).attr('href')` since `this` is now in the scope of thisObj.targetEl, and therefore points to the specific element clicked.